# while loop and promises

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm trying to better understand async behavior in terms of promises. I am trying to execute a promise using a forever while loop. I've already read several posts on how to do this but I want to understand why the following doesn't work.

**promises.js**

```
const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve('success');
    reject('failed');
});

while (true) {
    promise.then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

**Expected:**

```
$ node promises.js
success
success
success
success
...
```

Here the `...` means continuing forever.

**Actual:**

```
$ node promises.js
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 00007FF7E2D7F04A v8::internal::GCIdleTimeHandler::GCIdleTimeHandler+5114
 2: 00007FF7E2D5A0C6 node::MakeCallback+4518
 3: 00007FF7E2D5AA30 node_module_register+2032
 4: 00007FF7E2FE20EE v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+846
 5: 00007FF7E2FE201F v8::internal::FatalProcessOutOfMemory+639
 6: 00007FF7E3502BC4 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+9556
 7: 00007FF7E34F9C46 v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+24310
 8: 00007FF7E34F829C v8::internal::ScavengeJob::operator=+17740
 9: 00007FF7E3500F87 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2327
10: 00007FF7E3501006 v8::internal::Heap::MaxHeapGrowingFactor+2454
11: 00007FF7E30BCDB7 v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject+55
12: 00007FF7E3152CC6 v8::internal::WasmJs::Install+29414
13: 000001BD351DC5C1
```

Here the process just hangs then errors out.

My understanding is that because promises are async, using a standard while loop doesn't work. My guess is that the promises are being called (called as in `promise.then(...).catch(...)`) faster then they are being resolved?

What is causing the process to hang and then run out of heap memory?

Comment: It's an infinite loop.  There is no way to end the loop, that I see.

Comment: i'm not trying to end the loop.. i'm trying to understand why the Expected output is not happening

Comment: And every time through the loop you create new closures for the `.then` and `.catch` functions. Eventually you fill up memory with all those closures.

Comment: My assumption would be the continual operation of the loop is not allowing the ajax logic to start.  Javascript in the browser is single threaded

Comment: `while(true)` leads to an infinite call of your `promise`. And also your promise code itself is not correct because it calls `resolve` **and** `reject` everytime

Comment: You need to yield back to the event loop at least once for the promise to resolve. You're not doing that, you just indefinitely keep attaching more and more callbacks.

Comment: Promises are stored, then called later, that's how asynchronous code work. Your code is similar to pushing an element to an array in an infinite loop, which will cause a similar error. I recommend read more on [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: @JonathanM uh, no. no it would not. nothing other than `alert` and `confirm`  can pause a while loop that isn't in an `async` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this bit of code:

```
const promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve('success');
    reject('failed');
});

var x = 0
while (x < 50) {
    promise.then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    x++;
}
```

It's just like yours but it only runs the while loop 50 times. If you run this in chrome and set breakpoints, you'll find that first the `promise` variable is instantiated to the new Promise, and then the while loop starts, the line that says `promise.then..` runs, and then...

And then what you were expecting to happen next was perhaps the function inside the `.then` would run, but no, due to the asynchronous nature of promises, and the synchronous nature of `while`, it goes to `x++` and then back to `promise.then...` without ever running the internal function

The internal function is *scheduled* to run, but if the synchronous javascript never stops running, it never gets a chance to run. Javascript is single threaded, so your version of the loop keeps going forever and making more `.then` calls, filling up the stack and memory and breaking.

In my code, the function inside `.then(` runs AFTER x = 50, because that's when the while loop has ceased synchronously running.

---

edit

Consider, also, this bit of code:

```
var x = true;
function changeX(count) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        console.log('inside changeX');
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (count > 10) x = false;
            resolve();
        },100);
    })
}

async function run() {
   var count = 0;
   while(x) {
       await changeX(count);
       count++;
   }
   console.log('x is false now');
}

run();
```

Because this uses async await syntax, the while loop won't behave the same as your promises. If you run this through webpack/babel to convert it to es5 promises, you might find that it does something quite interesting.

Comment: this code makes still no sense....i cannot imagine a single usecase for this

Comment: @messerbill there is not a usecase for this. This is a toy to show him what's happening. That's why I spent the whole post explaining what's going on with promises.

Comment: thanks! that makes perfect sense